# VS Code highlight line and run in debug mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using PyCharm and have started using Visual Studio Code for Python.

In PyCharm during debug, I can highlight a line and run it using the Ctrl + Shift + r.

This is what I see in settings but when I do Shift + Enter it takes me to the terminal where it says variable not defined.

Python select line in Python terminal is set to Shift + Enter.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Open the `DEBUG CONSOLE` panel, then copy the code you want to run in the input box, with `Enter` to execute it.

**Reason:**

In the PyCharm, the code was sent to the `Debug` console, while not the `Python Console` console. But it's not available in the VSCode.